# How to parse web have user and password in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, http, request

I am a newbie in `flutter`, I would like to ask if there is a way to get information from a certain website (e.g. `facebook.com`) like take the name and print it out or not.

I need an example to understand them well. Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: do you want to scrap the website

Comment: maybe, because I can only parse a website that doesn't require login